# Writing a function to evaluate a string for specific ascii characters

Tags: string, function, ascii

I am writing a function in Jupyter Notebook to determine if a username meets specific character requirements. The character requirements are as follows:

Characters can be uppercase or lowercase or numbers. Additional characters that are allowed include +, - and _. I've figured out a function that works for this purpose, but I'm trying to understand why a similar function doesn't work.

The first set of code is the solution that I have found.

```
### This code works as expected ###
def valid_char(string):
    ascii_code = []
    spec_char = [43, 45, 95]
    upper_case = list(range(65,91))
    lower_case = list(range(97,123))
    numb = list(range(48,58))
    ascii_code = spec_char + upper_case + lower_case + numb
    for character in string:
        if ord(character) not in ascii_code:
            return False
    return True

Test_1 = 'Abc123+-_'
Test_2 = '$'
Test_3 = '['

print(valid_char(Test_1)) #True
print(valid_char(Test_2)) #False
print(valid_char(Test_3)) #False
```

I thought that this next set of code would work as well, but for some reason it doesn't produce the same results. I would really like to understand why.

```
### Why doesn't this function produce the same result as the first? ###
def ok_char(string):
    spec_char = [43, 45, 95]
    upper_case = list(range(65, 91))
    lower_case = list(range(97, 123))
    numb = list(range(48,58))
    for character in string: 
        if ord(character) in spec_char or upper_case or lower_case or numb:
                return True
    return False

Test_1 = 'Abc123+-_'
Test_2 = '$'
Test_3 = '['

print(ok_char(Test_1)) #True
print(ok_char(Test_2)) #True
print(ok_char(Test_3)) #True
```

Thanks for your help. I'm a novice just getting started.

#### Solution

```
### This function also works as expected ###
def ok_char(string):
    spec_char = [43, 45, 95]
    upper_case = list(range(65, 91))
    lower_case = list(range(97, 123))
    numb = list(range(48,58))
    for character in string:
        x = ord(character)
        if x in spec_char or x in upper_case or x in lower_case or x in numb:
                return True
    return False

Test_1 = 'Abc123+-_'
Test_2 = '$'
Test_3 = '['

print(ok_char(Test_1)) #True
print(ok_char(Test_2)) #False
print(ok_char(Test_3)) #False
```

Comment: `x in y or z` means `(x in y) or (z)`. What you want is `(x in y) or (x in z)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!